# Get Wacom CTL-480 to show up in gnome-control-center?

Tags: wacom, gnome-control-center

I have installed support for CTL-480 tablet as per: 
[Why is my Wacom Intuos tablet not detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359892/why-is-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-not-detected/406233#406233). Thus, the pen moves the pointer and clicking all the buttons on the pen works. However, the tablet does not show up in gnome-control-center > Wacom Graphics Tablet > which just displays "No tablet detected, Please plug in or turn on your Wacom tablet".

Do I need to update or install something to get it to show or is this settings manager independent of getting the drivers to work? I am trying to remap one of the buttons to middle click.

Ubuntu 12.10, Cinnamon.

Comment: I don't think anymore it's a duplicate. I have that tablet perfectly working on my 14.04, but it does not appear in control panel. The accepted answer do not work either (I had the package installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out -- I'm 90% sure this is what fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

(In the end it turned out the default button mapping was exactly what I wanted, I just need to enable autoscroll in my browser).

Comment: Not working anymore in 14.04. My tablet is working ok, but there is no hints of it in the control panel...