# Intuos Art CTH-490 doesn't works ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, wacom

My Wacom Intous art "Creative Pen & Touch" CTH-490, does not work with ubuntu 15.10. When I go to settings -> Wacom tablet, I see that there is no tablet detected, even if the tablet itself seems connected (the blue light is turned on) I tried to Google the problem and download some drivers but nothing worked.

I have no experience with ubuntu, and i have no idea what to do. Any help is welcomed :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite new tablet.

First of all, [sometime the tablet works even if it's not listed in the settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407017/get-wacom-ctl-480-to-show-up-in-gnome-control-center) --- try it in GIMP for example. It happens to me in several installations (I do not know why). Connect the tablet and issue the command

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

and see if it discovers any device.

Otherwise, you can try to compile and install the latest wacom driver, see  [Wacom Graphics Tablet CTH-480 / CTL-480 Not Detected In Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368242/wacom-graphics-tablet-cth-480-ctl-480-not-detected-in-ubuntu-13-10) --- maybe you're lucky. The instruction there are for an older version, but read it carefully and it should work for the new versions of the driver.

Last option, go to the the wacom on linux page and ask them for more help: http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: When I  launch the `xsetwacom --list devices` command, nothing happen :(