# Wacom Intuos 490 graphics tablet

Tags: gnome, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome, wacom

My husband bought me a Wacom Intuos 490 Tablet for Xmas. We have been all over the web searching for help loading it. No joy. My question is has anyone been able to load it in Ubuntu 15.10 and got it to work properly?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to install Ubuntu on your tablet?

Comment: (???) Load a computer in Ubuntu? What do you mean?

Comment: No I want to use the Wacom Intuos with Gimp on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/713059/16395

Answer (score 0):

A [Wacom Intuos 490](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets/intuos-comic#Specifications) is a graphics tablet that plugs into a PC.

The [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom.html) pages contain details for connecting these devices to an Ubuntu powered computer.

If you still have problems after following the Help pages, then please [edit] your question to include the specific details of what you have done, and what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not work.  The computer now, after a lot of work by my husband(retired IT professional), does detect the tablet but if you touch the stylus to the pad both the pad and the mouse lockup.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions for using your WACOM tablet on Ubuntu

Go to `System Settings`.

Open `Wacom Graphics Tablet`. If no tablet is detected, you'll be asked to Please plug in or turn on your `Wacom` tablet.

Click `Map to Monitor`

Check `Map to single monitor`.

Next to `Output`, select the monitor you wish to receive input from your graphics tablet. Only the monitors that are configured will be selectable.

You can use it as a tablet or as a trackpad style mouse by setting the Tracking Mode, select Tablet (absolute) or Touchpad (relative).

This is the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom.html)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this helped you click the check mark on the left to say thanks and help others identify a solution.