# 13.10 Intuos CTL 480/s

Tags: graphics-tablet

I cannot install this tablet - the instructions are all too complicated.

If anyone has time could they please write step by step instructions for someone like me who is just learning.

Thanks.

Comment: What instructions? You should just plug it in to a USB slot and should be able to use it in GIMP or Inkscape (or other similar apps).

Comment: The ones I found on the forums for cutting and pasting into the terminal - my graphics tablet does not seem to have drivers - plug it in and nothing happens so have searched the forums and found instructions on how to get them and install them with the terminal but they are all a bit complicated was wondering if someone could write simple instructions that anyone can understand - thanks.

Comment: The tablet is a ctl 480/s and am trying to use it under Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Comment: Please update your question with that information, including the link to the "instructions" you were trying to use, then. Provide as much information as you can about your issue in the question.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom

Comment: Trying to use info on that site as someone in another post

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/359892/why-is-my-wacom-intuos-tablet-not-detected    said it worked but cannot even unpack the tarball in the terminal says mike@mike-Lenovo-G500:~$ input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2/configure
bash: input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2/configure: No such file or directory
mike@mike-Lenovo-G500:~$ tar xjvf input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2
tar (child): input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mike@mike-Lenovo-G500:~$

Comment: The 480 is too new for 13.10. I have put step by step simplified instruction here: http://askubuntu.com/a/390795/16395 .

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have finally done it and here is how - kind of....

All of the info you need is here including links to the tarball (archive/ zip) with the drivers in it:

[Instructions for installation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom)

The problem I had was in understanding some of the terminology so here I am going to quickly explain so others will have less problems than I did - hopefully.

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)  # on Debian, Ubuntu, Mint

Uname in the above goes in just like that - it is not your user name or even if it is do not change it just cut and paste that into the terminal.

As far as I can see any spaces put/ not put when they should be will mess the whole thing up so make sure that if you are editing you get it all exactly as it should be - edit in a text editor then mess about with the spaces if it is not working.

tar xjvf input-wacom-.tar.bz2

You must use the version number of the driver you are using. I used input-wacom-0.20.0 so the above became:

tar xjvf input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2

You have to change to the directory the tarball is in to install it with something like cd ./username (insert yours there) / desktop - check that as I cannot remember the commands exactly but it is more or less that.

sudo cp .//wacom.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/input/tablet

For the above you have to get the kernel number by typing lsb_release -a I THINK - again check that but once you have got it put it in instead of  - ie. get rid of the funny brackets.

Best piece of advice - go on the Ubuntu channel in IRC chat and ask anything you don't know - people there really helped me and it was instant rather than posting and waiting for a reply.

Hope that is useful to any noobs like me out there - I certainly learnt a bit from the whole process at least I now know what a tarball is and can install the software in one.